# Referencing non-static variables from a static variable makes non-static variables destruct before static variable

Tags: c++, reference, static, destructor

Simply put: I want to write to a file whenever my program exits, so I have an object that accepts a filename (char*) and a reference to a Google Protobuf Message (for these purposes, you can just pretend that it's a string&) in the constructor and then writes the message to the filename in the destructor. Then, in main(), I initialise one of these objects and declare it as static (so it will destruct when the program exits for any reason).

My code had been working perfectly for several revisions before I changed something (seemingly) unrelated, and now it doesn't work. Now, when the object destructs, the char* and reference both point to unintialised versions of char and Message. I have the related code below:

```
using namespace std;

class WriteOnShutdown {
    private:
        const char* filename;
    public:
        MathHelper::Log& message;

        WriteOnShutdown(char* a, MathHelper::Log& b) : filename(a), message(b) {}
        ~WriteOnShutdown() {
            cout << "debug\n";
            //*filename is -52 (unitialised char)
            //READ ACCESS VIOLATION - message is still valid, but message.DebugString tries to call a pointer which hasn't been initialised yet
            cout << message.DebugString() << endl; 
        }
};

int main() {
    char filename[100];
    MathHelper::Log log;

    //Initialise filename and log

    static WriteOnShutdown write(filename, log);

    //Do program stuff here

    //Then, at the end of main(), printing write.message.DebugString() works like a charm
    cout << endl << write.message.DebugString();
    _getch();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you have a problem is following:

`MathHelper::Log log` is going to be destructed **before** your main returns, but destructor of `WriteOnShutdown` will be called **after** main returns.

Since `WriteOnShutdown` uses the reference to `log` in the destructor, you are accessing a 'dangling' reference, invoking undefined behavior and thus is seeing the problem.

And you have exactly the same problem with `filename` as well.

Obvious fix is to change `write` (which, by the way, is a terrible name for an object for several reasons) from being static to automatic variable.

Comment: Hey Sergey, I can understand how that would be a problem, but I have a few questions. 1 - I had it working before which led me to believe it wasn't that problem. 2 - How would I fix the problem without making the reference to a static variable?

Comment: @OttovonBisquick, this is often the case when you are in undefinied behavior land. It *works* due to memory layout, optimized code and other factors, and than suddenly breaks because of seemingly unrelated change. I am not sure what are you trying to do, so I am not sure about the best fix - but like I said, I can't see why your `write` needs to be static.

Comment: Sergey - yes, you are correct. I had gotten the idea from stackoverflow to make the variable static, but it makes more sense not to. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

This is called the [static initialization order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order) (which applies equally to destructors). It was always a problem, you just happened to get lucky earlier.

An easy way to fix that in your case is to change `const char* filename;` into `std::string &filename;` and `MathHelper::Log& message;` to `MathHelper::Log message;`. That way the memory will still be around by the time the destructor gets called.

Comment: No, it is not. This is not a problem with static objects initialization ordering.

Comment: Hey nwp, I had figured it was something like that and I appreciate your answer. But besides filename, there is a reason I am using a reference to MathHelp::Log - it's very big data. This is only a class project, though, so I _could_ change it to what you suggested, but I am interested if there is an alternative.

Comment: @OttovonBisquick Maybe you could make it a `shared_ptr`? Same safety effect without having to copy all the data.

Comment: I have just tried this, however the result is the same.